# How to do pinching zoom and swipe on multiple imageview in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pinchzoom

I am making multiple imageview in pager and also do zooming functionality on it. but if i keep zooming functionality on imageview in pager than bitmap cut on zoom.so how to display whole zooming bitmap in imageview without cut. I used Mike Ortiz's TouchImageView in pager for zooming.  advance in thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private AwesomePagerAdapter awesomeAdapter;
public static NonSwipeableViewPager awesomePager;
RelativeLayout v;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    awesomeAdapter = new AwesomePagerAdapter();
    awesomePager = (NonSwipeableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
    awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);
}
public class AwesomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private int NUM_VIEWS =2;
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_VIEWS ;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        if(position == 0){
        TouchImageView.b = true;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_gallery_image, null);
        TouchImageView tm = (TouchImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.swami);
        tm.setImageBitmap(bm);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(v, 0);
        }else if(position == 1){
            TouchImageView.b = true;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_gallery_image, null);
            TouchImageView tm = (TouchImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.swami);
            tm.setImageBitmap(bm);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(v, 0);
        }
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object view) {
        View v = (View) view;
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView(v);
        TouchImageView.b = true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((View) object);
    }

}
 }
```

swiper

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean enabled = true;

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (TouchImageView.b) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (TouchImageView.b) {

        try {
            enabled = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return enabled;
    }
    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

}
```

TouchImageView

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;
static  NonSwipeableViewPager PagerLeft;
// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;
static boolean b =false, c= false;
float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;

float width, height;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;
ViewGroup vp;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

public void setChild(ViewGroup vp) {
    this.vp = vp;
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            /*Log.v("log_tag",  event.getX()+" matrix "
                    + x);*/
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                TouchImageView.b = false;
                Log.v("event","ACTION_DOWN");
                last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                start.set(last);
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                    float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                    float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                    float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                    if (scaleWidth < width) {
                        deltaX = 0;
                        if (y + deltaY > 0){
                            TouchImageView.b = true;
                            Log.v("event","ACTION_MOVE  scaleWidth < width   y + deltaY > 0");
                            deltaY = -y;
                        }
                        else if (y + deltaY < -bottom){
                            TouchImageView.b = false;
                            Log.v("event","else ACTION_MOVE  scaleWidth < width   y + deltaY < -bottom");
                            deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                        }else{
                            TouchImageView.b = false;
                        }
                    } else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                        deltaY = 0;
                        if (x + deltaX > 0){
                            TouchImageView.b = true;
                            Log.v("event","ACTION_MOVE  scaleWidth < height x + deltaX > 0");
                            deltaX = -x;
                        }
                        else if (x + deltaX < -right){
                            TouchImageView.b = true;
                            Log.v("event","ACTION_MOVE  scaleWidth < height x + deltaX < -right");
                            deltaX = -(x + right);
                        }else{
                            TouchImageView.b = false;
                        }
                    }else {
                        if (x + deltaX > 0){
                            TouchImageView.b = true;
                            Log.v("event","scaleWidth > width");
                            deltaX = -x;
                        }
                        else if (x + deltaX < -right){
                            TouchImageView.b = true;
                            Log.v("event","else scaleWidth > width");
                            deltaX = -(x + right);
                        }
                        else{
                            TouchImageView.b = true;
                        }
                        if (y + deltaY > 0){
                            TouchImageView.b = true;
                            Log.v("event","y + deltaY");
                            deltaY = -y;
                        }
                        else if (y + deltaY < -bottom){
                            TouchImageView.b = true;
                            Log.v("event","y + deltaY < -bottom");
                            deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                        }else{
                            TouchImageView.b = false;
                        }
                    }
                    /*Log.v("log_tag",height + " matrix "
                            + (int) getHeightFromMatrix(matrix, TouchImageView.this));*/
                    matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                    last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.v("event","ACTION_UP");
                TouchImageView.b = true;
                mode = NONE;
                int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK){
                    Log.v("event","ACTION_UP  xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK");
                    performClick();
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                //TouchImageView.b = false;
                Log.v("event","ACTION_POINTER_UP");
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_3_DOWN:
                Log.v("event","ACTION_HOVER_MOVE");
                break;
            }
            /*getLayoutParams().height = (int) getWidthFromMatrix(matrix,
                    TouchImageView.this);
            getLayoutParams().width = (int) getHeightFromMatrix(matrix,
                    TouchImageView.this);*/
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    if (bm != null) {
        bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
        bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
    }
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @TargetApi(8)
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = (float) Math.min(
                Math.max(.95f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.05);
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }
        right = width * saveScale - width
                - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height
                - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        if (origWidth * saveScale <= width
                || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2,
                    height / 2);
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {
                        if (y < -bottom)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                        else if (y > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                    } else {
                        if (x < -right)
                            matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                        else if (x > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                    detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                if (x < -right)
                    matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                else if (x > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                if (y < -bottom)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                else if (y > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    // Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    float scaleX = (float) width / (float) bmWidth;
    float scaleY = (float) height / (float) bmHeight;
    scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    saveScale = 1f;

    // Center the image
    redundantYSpace = (float) height - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
    redundantXSpace = (float) width - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
    redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
    redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

    matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

    origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
    origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
    right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
    bottom = height * saveScale - height
            - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}

public static void setPager(NonSwipeableViewPager pagerLeft) {
    PagerLeft = pagerLeft;
}
  }
```

main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="fill"
>
<com.example.swipegallery.NonSwipeableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/awesomepager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

custom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="fill"
>


   <com.example.swipegallery.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
     /> 


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can u please help me i have followed your files code but unfortunately failed to run this application getting error in gen--->R.java file

Comment: can someone please help me how to do the same task with zoomin and zoomout button and this button should work for every page inside a single page we must be able to zoomin onclick of + button and similar for zoomout