# how to handel viewpager swipe disable on pinchzoom?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, zooming

I am new in viewpager component I am used custom viewpager with multiple images.and i want to do when my image in zooming mode during that period swiping disable and when swipe enable that time zooming enable. is it possible my code is here. advance in thanks.

Viewpager

```
public class SwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean enabled;

public SwipeableViewPager (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return false;
}



@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
```

}

imageview zoomig

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;
static  NonSwipeableViewPager PagerLeft;
// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;
static boolean b =false;
float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;

float width, height;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
 }


private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.v("event","ACTION_DOWN");
                TouchImageView.b = false;
                last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                start.set(last);
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {

                    float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                    float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                    float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                    float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                    if (scaleWidth < width) {
                        deltaX = 0;
                        if (y + deltaY > 0){
                            deltaY = -y;
                        }
                        else if (y + deltaY < -bottom){
                            deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                        }
                    } else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                        deltaY = 0;
                        if (x + deltaX > 0)
                            deltaX = -x;
                        else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                            deltaX = -(x + right);
                    }else {
                        if (x + deltaX > 0){
                            deltaX = -x;
                        }
                        else if (x + deltaX < -right){
                            deltaX = -(x + right);
                        }
                        if (y + deltaY > 0){
                            deltaY = -y;
                        }
                        else if (y + deltaY < -bottom){
                            deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                        }
                    }
                    matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                    last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.v("event","ACTION_UP");
                mode = NONE;
                int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK){
                    Log.v("event","ACTION_UP  xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK");
                    performClick();
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                TouchImageView.b = true;
                Log.v("event","ACTION_POINTER_UP");
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_3_DOWN:
                Log.v("event","ACTION_HOVER_MOVE");
                break;
            }
            /*getLayoutParams().height = (int) getWidthFromMatrix(matrix,
                    TouchImageView.this);
            getLayoutParams().width = (int) getHeightFromMatrix(matrix,
                    TouchImageView.this);*/
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    if (bm != null) {
        bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
        bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
    }
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @TargetApi(8)
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = (float) Math.min(
                Math.max(.95f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.05);
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }
        right = width * saveScale - width
                - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height
                - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        if (origWidth * saveScale <= width
                || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2,
                    height / 2);
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {
                        if (y < -bottom)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                        else if (y > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                    } else {
                        if (x < -right)
                            matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                        else if (x > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                    detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                if (x < -right)
                    matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                else if (x > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                if (y < -bottom)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                else if (y > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    // Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    float scaleX = (float) width / (float) bmWidth;
    float scaleY = (float) height / (float) bmHeight;
    scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    saveScale = 1f;

    // Center the image
    redundantYSpace = (float) height - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
    redundantXSpace = (float) width - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
    redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
    redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

    matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

    origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
    origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
    right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
    bottom = height * saveScale - height
            - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }

}
```

Comment: did you find an answer

Comment: yes George it's link of my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618447/how-to-do-pinching-zoom-and-swipe-on-multiple-imageview-in-android/13643000#13643000