# How can I render an ArrayList<ImageView> got from an AsyncTask in onPreExecute()?

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-asynctask, android-imageview

I'm new here and with Android development.

I'm trying to make a slide gallery with `ViewPager`.

This is my main activity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AbstractActivity {

    ArrayList<ImageView> imagens = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    ViewPager slideshow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        slideshow = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.slideshow);

        // inicia a task json
        new aTask(this).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void getResult(String result) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Home home = gson.fromJson(result, Home.class);

        imagens = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        for (Webdoor webdoor : home.webdoors) {
            try {
                ImageView img = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(webdoor.imagem)
                                .getContent());
                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                imagens.add(img);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class aTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ImageView>> {

        private HomeActivity homeActivityRef;

        public aTask(HomeActivity homeActivity) {
            this.homeActivityRef = homeActivity;
        }

        // inicio da task
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        // execução da tarefa em background
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ImageView> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(
                    new StringHttpMessageConverter());
            String result = restTemplate.getForObject(
                    "http://api.modahub.com.br/home", String.class,
                    "SpringSource");

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Home home = gson.fromJson(result, Home.class);

            ArrayList<ImageView> imagens = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

            for (Webdoor webdoor : home.webdoors) {
                try {
                    ImageView img = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                            .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(webdoor.imagem)
                                    .getContent());
                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    imagens.add(img);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            publishProgress(); // invoca o onProgressUpdate()
            return imagens;
        }

        // callback invocado pelo publishProgress()
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }

        // callback executado no final da task
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ImageView> aImagens) {
            // This variable aImagens is full of images!
            // How I put this on the screen =(
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make the list of `ImageView`s in `onPostExecute()` to be rendered in the screen?
Do I need a `Fragment` or a `Loader`?

Comment: First, you initialize the variable `imagens` multiple times...you don't want to do this. Second, I don't see where you declare the variable `aImagens` that you want to display

Comment: `aImagens` comes in as a method parameter in the `onPostExecute`.

Comment: @R.J missed that, sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make ImageGallery in ViewPager.than 
All images into ImageView bind in one adapter and you can bind adapter in View pager  see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618447/how-to-do-pinching-zoom-and-swipe-on-multiple-imageview-in-android/13643000#13643000)

Comment: In this link the adapter creates a view with a local resource. My problem is that my resource is in a json that that i can only use in the asynctask...

Comment: but you can make ArrayList<Bitmap> and than make multiple imageview in adapter and setposition .